# How to access MVC RouteData in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I can easily access the RouteData-Object in a C# MVC Controller via this code:

```
string idKeyName = "id";
if (RouteData.Values.ContainsKey(idKeyName))
{
    string hash = RouteData.Values[idKeyName].ToString();
}
```

But how can I do this in a SignalR-Hub without the direct access to the MVC-RouteData-Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on my own:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Segments.Last();
```

This is in fact not a RouteData-Object but it contains every part of the route as I need it.

This requires that the route of the referring site is like this (this is the default one for MVC):

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

You can use the Segments-Collection for every part of the route-values.